# Covering a countable metric space with finitely many subsets of bounded diameter

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $(X, d)$ is a metric space with countably many elements with the property that every finite subset of $X$ can be covered with three subsets of $X$ (some possibly empty) of diameter at most $1$. Can $X$ also be covered with three subsets of diameter at most $1$? The numerical values are actually arbitrary.

This problem has been bugging me for a week. I would appreciate any hints or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was also posted to Reddit where it was answered. See [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/math/comments/jb3ga0/simple_questions/g93rs70/) for the original answer.

I'll reproduce the proof here for completeness.

Enumerate the points of our metric space as $x_1, x_2, x_3, ....$ Let $X_n$ be the subspace with points ${x_1, ..., x_n}$. Let $B_{n, 1}, B_{n,2}, B_{n,3}$ be three subsets of $X_n$ of diameter at most $1$ that cover $X_n$. We want to construct sets $B_1, B_2, B_3$ of diameter at most $1$ that cover $X$. This is how we proceed.

First, we decide where $x_1$ goes. Select an index $i$ such that $x_1$ is in infinitely many of the $B_{n,i}$. Put $x_1$ in $B_i$.

Next we decide where $x_2$ goes. Select an index $j$ such that for infinitely many $n$, $x_1$ is in $B_{n,i}$ and $x_2$ is in $B_{n,j}$. Put $x_2$ in $B_j$.

The idea for $x_3$ is the same. Select an index $k$ such that for infinitely many $n$, $x_1$ is in $B_{n,i}$ and $x_2$ is in $B_{n,j}$ and $x_3$ is in $B_{n,k}$. Put $x_3$ in $B_k$. Repeat this to decide which $B$ every point of $X$ goes in.

$B_1, B_2, B_3$ cover $X$ because for every point of $X$ we've decided on a $B$ to put them in. Furthermore each $B$ has diameter at most $1$. Say $x_{i'}$ and $x_{j'}$ are both in $B_{k'}$. Then for infinitely many $n$, $x_{i'}$ and $x_{j'}$ are both in $B_{n,k'}$. Since $diam(B_{n,k'}) \leq 1, d(x_{i'}, x_{j'}) \leq 1$ so $diam(B_{k'}) \leq 1$.